# and sometimes I get failed spices because of Time.now, can't understand why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

so i have a method in model

```
class << self
  def last_week
    start = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week - 7.days
    finish = start + 7.days
    where('appointment_at >= ? AND appointment_at < ?', start, finish).order(appointment_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

And I write spec for this method.

```
RSpec.describe Appointment, type: :model, vcr: { record: :none } do
  let!(:time) { Time.now }
  let(:appointment_at) { time }

  context '.last_week' do
    let!(:scoped_appointment) { create(:appointment, appointment_at: time - 2.days) }
    let!(:another_appointment) { create(:appointment, appointment_at: time - 16.days) }

    it do
      travel_to(time) do
        expect(Appointment.last_week).to include(scoped_appointment)
        expect(Appointment.last_week).not_to include(another_appointment)
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

And sometime i get failed this spec with error.

```
expected #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> to include #<Appointment id: 18, lead_id: 27, body: nil, appointment_at: "2019-02-25 00:59:47", google_id: nil, ... "pending", user_id: 22, notify: nil, cc_emails: nil, appointment_minutes: nil, status_message: nil>
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[#<Appointment id: 18, lead_id: 27, body: nil, appointment_at: "2019-02-25 00:59:47", google_id: nil, created_at: "2019-02-27 00:59:47", updated_at: "2019-02-27 00:59:47", timezone: nil, subject: "Meeting with Lead", address: nil, notification: nil, status: "pending", user_id: 22, notify: nil, cc_emails: nil, appointment_minutes: nil, status_message: nil>]
   +[]
```

I can't understand why?

And I have a suggestion that I should tightly set `time`

in `spec_helper.rb`

```
$now = DateTime.parse('2020-01-01 00:00:01 -0500')
```

will it be right? and why ?

Comment: Don't use a global. See my answer on your other question for the reasoning.

Comment: I wonder if the failure has anything to do with VCR? Have you tried removing VCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test setup is brittle. It will break depending on the day of the week you run your spec.

The scope in your model returns appointments from the previous week, Monday through Sunday (you are calling `beginning_of_week` and adding 7 days to it)

So if your tests run on a Wednesday, like in the example you provided, the appointment’s  `appointment_at` field will be set to Monday (since you are calculating it as `Time.now - 2.days`). That means your scope will not cover that appointment.

I suggest you use a specific time in your setup. Given your current setup, using `let(:time) { DateTime.parse('2019-02-25 00:00:00') }` should work